# How can I get a list of synonyms that work across all contexts?

Tags: language, english

Many synonyms are context specific. For example "force" is a synonym for "drive" in the context of urging or inspiring, but not in the context of journeying by vehicle.

Other synonyms seem to work across all contexts, for example "sea" and "ocean".

How can I get a list of all synonyms that work across all contexts?

**Update**

Reflecting on [TimLymington's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280437/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-synonyms-that-work-across-all-contexts?noredirect=1#comment621782_280437), is there some measure of synonym distance?

Consider some of the words that [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sea) offer as synonyms for sea: expanse, lake, ocean, pond, surf, abundance and blue. Intuitively, I'm confident I can replace sea with ocean more often than with blue. So I could say ocean has a shorter synonym distance from sea than blue.

How can I measure this distance? And, back to my question of a list, how can I get a list of all synonyms with distances?

(n.b. same question on [English stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280437/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-synonyms-that-work-across-all-contexts))

Comment: this may be a question to ask on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @albert right, it sits across both. I've added a copy to the English SE

Comment: What you need is to determine how many meanings a word ('term') has -- as each meaning ('concept') might have different synonyms.  Also consider a full fledged thesaurus (thesaurus.com and Roget's Thesaurus are 'synonym rings', not thesauri in the library science sense of the word), as they might distinguish between spelling variations (always the same), synonyms (the same for that concept) and equivalent terms (roughly the same for that concept).

Comment: @OllieGlass cool....wasn't sure exactly where it sat, but hopefully between the two you get your answer

Comment: @albert sadly it's had a terrible reception on the English SE https://twitter.com/ollieglass/status/655002886255026177

Comment: Very bizarre response from English SE. Hopefully OD can do better.

Answer (score 2):

*This isn't a super answer, but maybe it can start some discussion...*

1. Let's consider only topical words, so *ocean*, *sea*, *lake*, *pond*, *river*, and *stream*.
2. Let's then download (scrape) as many dictionary, thesaurus and encyclopedia entries as possible, and dump the results as text files *ocean.txt*, *sea.txt*, etc...
3. Remove [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) such as *the* from each of the *.txt* files
4. Compute frequencies of other words (with same part of speech) that appear in the *.txt* file.
5. Using a simple definition as an example, we can parse the text and count the most frequent words: sample python 2.7 code

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

   import string
   from collections import Counter

   text = '''noun: ocean; plural noun: oceans

   a very large expanse of sea, in particular each of the main areas into which the sea is divided geographically.
   "the Atlantic Ocean"
   synonyms:   (the) sea; informalthe drink;
   informalthe briny;
   informalsalt chuck;
   literarythe deep, the waves, the main, the foam, the profound;
   moana
       North American
       the sea.
       noun: the ocean
       "they scramble across the beach to the ocean and plunge into the surf"
       informal
       a very large expanse or quantity.
       "she had oceans of energy"
       synonyms:   a lot, a great/large amount, a great/good deal, plenty, quantities, an abundance, a profusion; informallots, loads, heaps, bags, masses, stacks, oodles, tons, scads;
       informallashings, a shedload;
       informalgobs;
       informala swag;
       vulgar slanga shitload;
       vulgar slangan assload
       "she had oceans of energy"

   Origin
   Middle English: from Old French occean, via Latin from Greek ōkeanos     ‘great stream encircling the earth's disc’. ‘The ocean’ originally denoted the whole body of water regarded as encompassing the earth's single land mass.
   '''

   text = text.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation) # remove punctuation
   text = text.lower()
   word_freq = Counter(text.split())

   for word, count in word_freq.most_common(10):
       print word, '\t',count
   ```

gives as an output

```
the     16
a   7
of  5
sea     4
ocean   4
oceans  3
noun    3
synonyms    2
had     2
main    2
```

Removing stop words, we can see that **sea** shows up 4 times, while the other "bodies of water" words don't show up. (The words *beach*, *waves* and *shitload* each show up once, interestingly.)

6. With enough text data for each word, you can build synonym distances. I'd guess that for articles related to "ocean", **sea** will show up 10x more than lake and river.